# How to confirm a form submission via pop-up, not a redirect?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, popup, contacts

I've been looking around for solutions to a particular issue I'm having with a PHP script I'm trying to re-purpose.

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent = "$name \nMessage: $message";
$recipient = "me@me.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die ("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . " <a href = '../index.html' style = 'text-decoration:none;color:#ff0099;'>Return Home</a>";
?>
```

Instead of re-directing to another page, I'm keen to understand a clean way of just initiating a confirmation via modal pop-up instead.

I'm running the script as an external file so I'm guessing there's half the answer already but in terms of invoking a jQuery plugin to do the rest of the work, I could use a pointer or two!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could use this in the onsubmit attribute

```
onSubmit="javascript: return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this?');"
```

Will ask for ok/cancel confirmation

--- jQuery Ajax -----

```
function doSubmit(){
  var postData = jQuery('#your-form-id').serialize();    

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'form-action.php',
    data: postData
  }).done(function( html ) {
    alert(html);
  });
}
```

-- and in your form tag ---

```
<form id="your-form-id" onsubmit="javascript: doSubmit();" ...
```

Comment: k -jQuery or Prototype or vanilla JS? you will need to use an asynchronous call to do this without a redirect - let me know which framework you want the example in and I will code you a simple example :)

Comment: Well I was planning to do this in jQuery and cheers for the pointer!

Comment: There - the jQuery based one will alert the msg that you echo out at the end of your PHP processor script there.

Comment: This looks great, I'll give it a shot and see how it goes, cheers again from one Ben to another!

Answer (score 1):

Th need to post via AJAX if you don't want to reload or redirect to a new page.

On the "success" method of the AJAX call you would then trigger your dialog.

Comment: Thanks Diodeus, I'll take a look into this and see what I can find.

Answer (score 1):

- Wrap all the html inputs in a form element.
- on click of the send mail link, attach an ajax event to send an ajax POST request to the php file which contains the business logic of sending mail (the one as
  shown in your question).
- Then On success of the event you can show the Success message to User.
- For implementing this with minimal
  code, i would suggest you to use a combination of JQuery (For ajax
  form post)  and Twitter Bootstrap (For CSS and modal window)
- some implementation like code below may help you

$('#divId').click(function () {

```
//start the ajax
$.ajax({
    //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
    url: "send_mail.php",

    //POST method is used
    type: "POST",
    // here we are serializing all form values ( its is not php serialize)
    data: $("#Form").serialize(),
    //Do not cache the page
    cache: false,

    //success
    success: function (html) {             
        if (html=='1') {    
            $('#divModal').modal('show') ; 

        }              
    }      
});

//cancel the submit button default behaviours
return false;
```

});

Answer (score 0):

As Diodeus suggests you should use a HTTP request to call you php file. With the output you get back from the request you can create a popup or whatever you want to inform the user. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp) you find some basis information on how to do that.